# Recently started of learning Java, I wanted to create app which counts number of clicks

Tags: java, swing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/firZv.png)
I wanted to create the app which counts number of clicks, and when I added second button it counts both of lines instead of only 1, for example if I click on the first button it should count only first line, also for the second button. But it counts both of lines no matter which button I click on

Here me code:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Main implements ActionListener {
    private int number2 = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Main(){
        frame = new JFrame();


        JButton button = new JButton("1st Player");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("2nd Player");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button1.addActionListener(this);


        label = new JLabel("1. Number of clicks: 0 ");
        label1 = new JLabel("2. Number of clicks: 0 ");



        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50,50,10,50));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2 ));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(label1);

        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("My first GUI");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        count++;
        number2++;
        label.setText("1. Number of clicks: " + count);
        label1.setText("2. Number of clicks: " + number2);

    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand why the values of `count` and `number2` can never be different?

Comment: At the beggining I used count++ for both of them, it didn' work then I added ```number2```. It didn't work too

Comment: But do you understand why? That the lines of code to increment each of those variables, `count++;` and `number2++;` are executed one after the other, so the values can never be different.

Comment: I do not understand that part, I just tried.

Answer (score 0):

The method `actionPerformed` is called for both buttons and it increases both counters at the same time. If you want to have 2 separate counters, you need to have two different ActionListeners, each one increasing the counter of the right button.

Comment: If I create one more ```actionPerformed``` it says me ```'actionPerformed(ActionEvent)' is already defined in 'com.company.Main'```

Comment: You will need two classes, each of which implement `ActionListener`.

Comment: Got you, let me try it